# Renaming files (while counting the number)

Tags: python, rename

I'm currently trying to write a python script to rename a bunch of files. The file is named like this: [Name][Number]-[Number]. To give a specific example: milk-00-00. The next file is milk-00-01, then 02, 03 until X. After that milk-01-00 starts with the same pattern.

What I need to do is to switch 'milk' into a number and replace the '-XX-XX' by '-01', '02', ...

I hope you guys get the idea. The current state of my code is pretty poor, it was hard enough to get it this far though. It looks like this and with this I'm at least able to replace something. I'll also manage to get rid of the 'milk' with the help of google. However, if there is an easier way, I'd really appreciate a push in the right direction!

```
import os
import sys
path = 'C:/Users/milk/Desktop/asd'
i=00

for filename in os.listdir(path):
if filename.endswith('.tiff'):
    newname = filename.replace('00', 'i')
    os.rename(filename,newname)
    i=i+1
```

Comment: So you have a series of files with names like 'milk-01-03' and you want to switch them into a single number with out the alphanumeric part i.e. in this case 'N' where N is X+1+3?

Comment: Hey there, thanks for answering!

The files are named (sorry, didn't manage to get a list out...)
-milk-00-01
-milk-00-02
-milk-00-03
-milk-01-01
-milk-01-02

Comment: Gladly, I just need to confirm the output :) - so you want them to be '01', '02','03','04','05'?

Comment: I actually want them to be for example '1000-01', '1000-02', ... '1002-01', '1002-02'... (it's not a problem to e.g. take the '1000'-files and put them into a folder to rename them!)

Comment: So '00-01' becomes '1000-01' and '01-01' becomes '1002-01'? Or '1001-01'?

Comment: 01-01 becomes 1001-01!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `format` function

```
temp = (' ').join(filename.split('.')[:-1])
os.rename(filename, '10{}-{}.tiff'.format(temp.split('-')[-2],temp.split('-')[-1]))
```

Since `filename` has the `.tiff` extension this program first creates a version of `filename` without the extension - `temp` - and then creates new names from that.

Comment: Hey there! Thanks so far :)

I in fact want to keep tiff extension. I'll try to clarify my naming convention again:

So I have milk-00-01.tiff  and I need 1000-01.tiff. For milk-00-02.tiff I'd need 1000-02.tiff and for milk-01-00.tiff I'd need 1001-00.tiff. I hope this helps.

I'll try the code you suggested out nevertheless. Thanks :)

Comment: @awake - this should work! :) i.e. this one should produce your actual desired result (I assume that `i` was just for counting and dropped it in my answer).

Comment: Actually, since your `filename` has a `tiff` extension it turns out a little bit longer, check it out.

Answer (score 1):

```
    os.rename(filename, '1000-%02d.tiff' % i)
    i += 1
```